# Uninstalling CVSNT and installing it again

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs, cvsnt

I was using CVSNT (2.5.03.2382) and I installed TortoiseCVS (TortoiseCVS-1.12.5.exe). CVSNT is now stopped working. Clients could not connect to CVSNT. I uninstalled TortoiseCVS but CVSNT is still not working. If I uninstall and re-install CVSNT, will by code and history be safe? Code repository is in a separate folder (untouched). Will the new install pick up the code (branches, history, etc) if I point to the same repository? Thanks.

Comment: You really should look why you can't get any connections to the repository. It is very likely some network equipment or firewall settings changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and reainstall CVS(NT) at will, as long as you don't touch the repository and the version you install is compatible with the repository. After an installation you just need to configure the server to point to the correct repository.

Beware that installing Tortoise may not be enough. You need a CVS(NT) server to access the repository (unless you use the deprecated "local" protocol).

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug.

Tortoise comes with a newer version of CVSNT.  Unfortunatelly, during install, CVSNT does not completely remove the older version and you get a mix of 2.5.03 and 2.5.05 which does not work.

The solution is:

- Uninstall ***all versions*** of CVSNT
- Reinstall CVSNT 2.5.05 (alternatively, uninstall and reinstall Tortoise)

Things should work afterwards.